# How to zip two Observables in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

In my app I have two services and both of them have a method that makes a requests and then returns an Observable of different type.

I want to display in a RecyclerView a list composed of the result of combining these two Observables. I googled about this and found the zip() method that seems to do exactly what I want. I'm trying to implement it but I don't know how to do it correctly.

While I was googling, I came up with this [this article](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-make-complex-requests-simple-with-rxjava-in-kotlin-ccec004c5d10) which seems to explain it clearly. Even though the author is using Singles while I am using Observables.

As far as I understand how `zip()` works, I know  I have to pass every Observable I want to "zip" and then I must specify a function that will compose my final Observable, right?

This is my code so far:

```
interface InvitationService {
    @GET("foo/{userId}")
    fun getFooByUser(@Path("userId") userId: String): Observable<Response<ArrayList<Foo>>>
}

interface InvitationService {
    @GET("bar/{userId}")
    fun getBarByUser(@Path("userId") userId: String): Observable<Response<ArrayList<Bar>>>
}

class FooRemoteDataSource : FooDataSource {
    private var apiService: FooService

    fun getFooByUser(userId:String) {
        return apiService.getFooByUser(userId)
    }
}

class BarRemoteDataSource : BarDataSource {
    private var apiService: BarService

    fun getBarByUser(userId:String) {
        return apiService.getBarByUser(userId)
    }

}

class FooRepository(private val remoteDataSource: InvitationRemoteDataSource) : FooDataSource {

    override fun getFooByUser(userId: String): Observable<Response<ArrayList<Foo>>> {
        return remoteDataSource.getFooByUser(userId)
    }
}

class BarRepository(private val remoteDataSource: BarRemoteDataSource) : BarDataSource {

    override fun getBarByUser(userId: String): Observable<Response<ArrayList<Bar>>> {
        return remoteDataSource.getBarByUser(userId)
    }
}
```

And here is where I'm actually stuck:

```
class ListPresenter(var listFragment: ListContract.View?, 
                        val fooRepository: FooRepository,
                        val barRepository: BarRepository) : ListContract.Presenter {

    fun start() {
        loadList()
    }

    private fun loadLists() {
        //HERE IS WHERE IM STUCK

        Observable.zip(fooRepository.getFooByUser(userId).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                barRepository.getBarByUser(userId).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                )

        // AFTER 'ZIPPING' THE OBSERVABLES 
        // I NEED TO UPDATE THE VIEW ACCORDINGLY
    }
}
```

I don't know how to call `zip()` properly, I know that I must pass a function but I don't get it because in the article linked above the author is using a `Function3` because he has 3 Observables.

As I only have 2, I don't know how to do it. If open curly braces after a comma inside the method args, it requires me to return a `BiFunction<ArrayList<Foo>, ArrayList<Bar>>` which is what I don't know how to specify.

Would someone explain it to me?

Comment: the article is from 2017 and uses RxJava, today you should be using RxKotlin. See my answer on how to do so. :)

Comment: Okay I will make the change as soon as I get home @WilliMentzel

Comment: did it work? :)

Answer (score 3):

For Kotlin you should use [RxKotlin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxkotlin/2.3.0) rather than RxJava. `BiFunction`, `Function3` come from RxJava. With RxKotlin you can use lambdas instead.

---

> As far as I understand how zip() works, I know I have to pass every Observable I want to "zip" and then I must specify a function that will compose my final Observable, right?

Correct, and here is a minimal example, which demonstrates how to do it.

**Example 1**

```
val observable1 = listOf(1, 2, 3).toObservable()
val observable2 = listOf(4, 5, 6).toObservable()
val zipped = Observables.zip(observable1, observable2) { o1, o2 -> o1 * o2}
```

In this example you have two observables, each emitting integers. You pass them to `zip` and as third argument a lambda which defines a way to "cobmine them". In this case it multiplies them.

The resulting observable `zipped` will emit: 4, 10 and 18.

---

**Example 2**

Here another example zipping three observables which are not all of the same type:

```
val obs1 = listOf("on", "tw", "thre").toObservable()
val obs2 = listOf("n", "o", "e").toObservable()
val obs3 = listOf(1, 2, 3).toObservable()
val zipped = Observables.zip(obs1, obs2, obs3) { o1, o2, o3 -> 
    "$o1$o2 = $o3"
}
```

Here, each element of the resulting observable will be a string: "one = 1", "two = 2", "three = 3"

Comment: If I try that, it won't work. In your example the two Observables are from the same type! Mines aren't and I think that is the problem, if open curly braces after a comma in the method, it will require me to return a BiFunction<ArrayList<Foo>, ArrayList<Bar>> which is what I don't know how to speciy

Comment: @MarcosStival pls use rxKotlin rather than rxJava: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxkotlin/2.3.0

Comment: Okay, when I get home I will make the change to RxKotlin

Comment: Won't it be too much overhead? There should be an easier way to do what I want instead of using the zip method, right?

Comment: @MarcosStival it depends. If you want to do it with Rx ...zip would be the best way IMHO :)

Answer (score 1):

**Zipping two Observables of different types using BiFunction**

```
override fun getCommoditiesAndAddresses() {
    view.showProgress()
    view.hideViews()
    Observable.zip(Commo24Retrofit.createAuthService(RateAPIService::class.java)
            .getCommodities(),
            Commo24Retrofit.createAuthService(RateAPIService::class.java)
                    .getLocations(GetLocationsRequest(getOrgId())),
            BiFunction { commodityResponse: GetCommoditiesResponse, locationsResponse: GetLocationsResponse ->
                handleCommoditiesAndAddresses(commodityResponse, locationsResponse)
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                view.hideProgress()
                view.showViews()
                view.handleCommodities(it?.commodities)
                view.handleLocations(it?.locations)
            }, { throwable ->
                view.hideProgress()
                view.handleFailure(throwable.getErrorMessage(context))
            })
}
```

Look, how I'm handling the response:

```
private fun handleCommoditiesAndAddresses(commodityResponse: GetCommoditiesResponse, locationsResponse: GetLocationsResponse): CommoditiesAddresses {
        return CommoditiesAddresses(commodityResponse.commodityList, locationsResponse.addressList)
    }
```

Here, check the API Service:

```
interface RateAPIService {

    @POST("get-org-address")
    fun getLocations(@Body getLocationsRequest: GetLocationsRequest): Observable<GetLocationsResponse>

    @POST("get-commodity-list")
    fun getCommodities(): Observable<GetCommoditiesResponse>
    }
```

If you have any doubt you can comment it out.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it look like you had to do the exact same thing, as soon as I get home I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, had to the exact same thing, give it a try and if there something you need to know I'll help you out. It is MVP architecture. and I'm doing it in the presenter.